# How to save a video after changing its speed with opencv in your folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, save, video-processing

Used: OpenCV and Python3

I am using Python 3.8.2

Operating System: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

I tried this code on VScode, it does show a video with  changed speed with the `cv2.imshow` command but I don't know how to save that changed video in my folder:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Pothole testing.mp4')
frameTime = 100 

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(frameTime) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Can anyone tell me what should I add to this code so that the changed video gets saved? And preferably in the .mp4 format itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fps parameter of the [`cv2.VideoWriter()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ad59c61d8881ba2b2da22cff5487465b5) method. The fps can be calculated by simple diving your `frameTime` variable by `1000`, as the `cv2.waitKey()` method takes in a number and uses it as a thousandth of a second.

Note that if the `cap` never closed during the `while` loop, the `while cap.isOpened()` won't be any better than `while True`, meaning by the time the last frame is read, an error would occur, causing the `writer.release()` method to never be called, thus making the resulting file unreadable.

Here is how I would do it:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Pothole testing.mp4')
ret, frame = cap.read() # Get one ret and frame 
h, w, _ = frame.shape # Use frame to get width and height
frameTime = 100

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID") # XVID is the ID, can be changed to anything
fps = 1000 / frameTime # Calculate fps
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("Pothole testing 2.mp4", fourcc, fps, (w, h)) # Video writing device

while ret: # Use the ret to determin end of video
    writer.write(frame) # Write frame
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(frameTime) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    ret, frame = cap.read()

writer.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If all you need is the resulting file and not the progress window, you can omit a few lines:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Pothole testing.mp4')
ret, frame = cap.read()
h, w, _ = frame.shape
frameTime = 100

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
fps = 1000 / frameTime
writer = cv2.VideoWriter("Pothole testing 2.mp4", fourcc, fps, (w, h))

while ret:
    writer.write(frame)
    ret, frame = cap.read()

writer.release()
cap.release()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, the only thing I had to change was from XVID to mp4v for mp4.